# System.Reactive Schedulers DueTime scheduling

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I need to build a queue which takes items associated with actions to be executed at a specific point in time in a non-blocking way. That means that every action associated to the item should be executed on a separate thread.

A few days ago I stumbled on `System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler` interface and the schedulers built-in into `System.Reactive`. What especially caught my interest is the `Schedule<TState>(TState, TimeSpan, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable>)` overload of the `Schedule()` method.

This overload - in conjunction with - `Scheduler.ThreadPoolScheduler`, `Scheduler.TaskPoolScheduler` or `NewThreadScheduler` seems to be what I need.

That is why I wrote a little quick-and-dirty program to compare those schedulers, which you can find at the bottom of this post. Unfortunately, the consistency check fails for all schedulers, meaning that some items that have been scheduled to be executed later, have been executed before items to be executed earlier.

Is this due to the nature of those Schedulers (time to fire up a new thread/task messes up the order?) ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RxDueTimeScheduling
{
    public class ScheduledItem
    {
        public TimeSpan Delay;
        public DateTime EnqueueTime;
        public DateTime DueTime;        
        public double Fault;
        public double ExecutionTime;
    }

class Program
{
    private static AutoResetEvent mWait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static long mEnqueueingFinishedAfter;
    private static int mMinDelay = 10;
    private static int mMaxDelay = 500;
    private static int mMessagesPerTest = 50;
    private static List<ScheduledItem> mResultList;
    private static Stopwatch mTestStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    private static Stopwatch mExecutionStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    private static object mLockObject =  new Object();
    private static string mFormatString = "mm:ss:fffff"; // ATTENTION: not displaying hours to make output fit into one line in console
    private static volatile int mCounter;
    private static volatile int mLogCounter;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testData = CreateTestData(mMinDelay, mMaxDelay,    mMessagesPerTest);
        RunTest(Scheduler.NewThread, testData);            
        RunTest(Scheduler.TaskPool,testData);
        RunTest(Scheduler.ThreadPool, testData);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("All Tests finished. Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }


    private static void RunTest(IScheduler scheduler, List<int> testData)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("------- new test with " + scheduler.GetType().Name + " -------------");
        mCounter = 1;
        mLogCounter = 0;            
        mEnqueueingFinishedAfter = 0;
        mResultList = new List<ScheduledItem>();            
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        mTestStopWatch.Restart();
        w.Restart();           
        testData.ForEach(d =>
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(d);
            var item = new ScheduledItem()
            {
                Delay = delay,
                EnqueueTime = now,
                DueTime = now + delay,                    
            };

            scheduler.Schedule(item, item.Delay, myActionFunc);                
        });
        w.Stop();
        mEnqueueingFinishedAfter = w.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (!mWait.WaitOne(mMaxDelay*mMessagesPerTest))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not finish test {0} in {1} seconds. Messages Processed {2}", scheduler.GetType().Name, (mMaxDelay*mMessagesPerTest/1000), mResultList.Count );
            PrintStats(scheduler);
        }
    }


    private static List<int> CreateTestData(int minDelay, int maxDelay, int count)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var nextDelay = r.Next(minDelay, maxDelay);
            result.Add(nextDelay);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Func<IScheduler, ScheduledItem, IDisposable> myActionFunc = new Func<IScheduler, ScheduledItem, IDisposable>(OnDequeued);


    private static IDisposable OnDequeued(IScheduler scheduler, ScheduledItem item)
    {
        DateTime? now = null;
        lock (mLockObject)            
        {

            mExecutionStopWatch.Restart();            
            now = DateTime.Now;
            item.Fault = (now.Value - item.DueTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            mResultList.Add(item);
        }


            Console.WriteLine(
                mLogCounter++ +
                ":{0} scheduled on {1} for execution on {2}, fault in ms: {3} delay in ms:{4}, thread: {5}",
                now.Value.ToString(mFormatString),
                item.EnqueueTime.ToString(mFormatString),
                item.DueTime.ToString(mFormatString),
                item.Fault,
                item.Delay.TotalMilliseconds,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            if (mCounter++ == mMessagesPerTest)
            {
                mTestStopWatch.Stop();
                PrintStats(scheduler);
                mWait.Set();
            }
            mExecutionStopWatch.Stop();
            item.ExecutionTime = mExecutionStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            return null;            
    }

    private static void PrintStats(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var consistencyErrors = ConsistencyCheck(mResultList);
        string consistencyResultString = Environment.NewLine + (consistencyErrors.Count == 0
                                            ? "Consistency Check passed."
                                            : "Consistency Errors item: " + string.Join(",",consistencyErrors).TrimEnd(','));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Test: {0} Duration: {1} Enqueueing: {2} Average Fault: {3} Max Fault: {4} Cosistency Check Result: {5}, Average ExeTime: {6} Max ExeTime: {7}",
                                        scheduler.GetType().Name,
                                        mTestStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                                        mEnqueueingFinishedAfter,
                                        (int) mResultList.Average(r => r.Fault),
                                        (int) mResultList.Max(r => r.Fault),
                                        consistencyResultString,
                                        mResultList.Average(r => r.ExecutionTime),
                                        mResultList.Max(r => r.ExecutionTime)
                              ));
    }

    private static List<int> ConsistencyCheck(List<ScheduledItem> resultList)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 1; i<resultList.Count;i++)
        {
            var item = resultList[i];
            var previousItem = resultList[i-1];

            if (item.DueTime < previousItem.DueTime)
            {
                result.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `Schedule<TState>(TState, TimeSpan, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable>)` overload delays the unit of work by the specified time period. In your test, you are specifying random delays for each item, and then testing the order of execution in the ordinal sense. For delays smaller than the timer resolution, the work is scheduled immediately.

If you want ordering of execution, you can go with `EventLoopScheduler`.